# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null , ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, textbox

[image]Can any body please help what's the problem in this code?
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
I have this code in my PartialView

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>

            <th>
                Products

            </th>
            <th>
                Quantity

            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
                </td>

                <td> 
             <input type='text' name='qty@(item.Product)' id='qty@(item.ProductId)'/>

                <Button class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-plus" name="add" onclick='javascript: document.getElementById("qty").value++;' value='+' />
                <Button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-minus" name="subtract" onclick='javascript: subtractQty(qty@(item.ProductId));' value='-' />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="update();">Ok</button>
            </td> 

            </tr>
        }

    </table>

And JavaScript in my Index.cshtml:


   function subtractQty(name) {
            if (document.getElementById(name).value - 1 < 0)
                return;
            else
               document.getElementById(name).value--;
        }
```

I'am trying to put textbox in my @foreach PartialView page
Thank you in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

The onClick event for your add button is:

`onclick='javascript: document.getElementById("qty").value++;`

The "qty" should be "qty@(item.ProductId)" so that it uses the values in your loop.

The onClick event for your subtract button is:

```
onclick='javascript: subtractQty(qty@(item.ProductId));'
```

The argument to subtractQty should be enclosed in quotes.

Here's a working example without the templating variables

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function subtractQty(name) {
            if (document.getElementById(name).value - 1 < 0)
                return;
            else
               document.getElementById(name).value--;
        }
</script>
<table class="table">
        <tr>

            <th>
                Products

            </th>
            <th>
                Quantity

            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

            <tr><td>
             <input type='text' name='qty' id='qty' value="0"/>

                <Button class="btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-plus" name="add" onclick='javascript: document.getElementById("qty").value++;' value='+' />
                <Button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-minus" name="subtract" onclick='javascript: subtractQty("qty");' value='-' />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="update();">Ok</button>
            </td> 

            </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: Rahul VaidyaBut every click goes to the first textbox becouse all textbos have the same name. Please chek my coade again, have updated with picture